# Foreach error when checking data from database

Tags: c#

I am working on a small piece of code to loop through my database data. I get to rows from the database and want loop through one with an foreach. Then within the foreach, I am currently trying to make a console message so I can see if it works.

The function `Common.Log` is a function made by myself and a co-worker.

This is the code:

```
SqlParameter bonIdParam = new SqlParameter("bonId", bonId);
DataTable controleTable = RidderQuery(controleQuery, bonIdParam);
DataRow controleRow = controleTable.Rows[0];

int code= controleRow .Field<int>("CODE");
int productionDone = queryRow.Field<int>("PRODUCTIONDONE"); // 1 = true, 0 = false

foreach(int checkedCode in controleRow .Field<int>("CODE"))
{
    Common.Log(checkedCode.ToString);
}
```

The problem that I have is, that the foreach loop does not work. yes I know that very unclear, but I don't know how to explain it better.
So these are the errors im getting:

> - Error 3: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'
> - Error 1: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'int' because 'int' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
> - Error 2: The best overloaded method match for 'LocatieVerwerkingWifi.Common.Log(string)' has some invalid arguments

What can I do to fix these errors? I think the problem is in this line:

```
foreach(int checkedCode in queryRow.Field<int>("CODE"))
```

But I don't understand what is going wrong. Can someone explain/help me with this issue?

Comment: You haven't shown the declaration or initialization of `queryRow`. Also, `heckedCode.ToString` must be `heckedCode.ToString()` in C#.

Comment: Should be controleRow

Comment: Like i said Common.Log is a function of myself so yues Common.Log

Comment: Common is the class, so common used functions like the Log funtion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `controleRow` is a `DataRow` and `controleRow.Field<int>("CODE")` returns a single int-field which you can't enumerate.
- in C# `checkedCode.ToString` must be `checkedCode.ToString()`.

Maybe you want to loop all rows:

```
foreach(DataRow row in controleTable.Rows)
{
    int checkedCode =  row.Field<int>("CODE");
    Common.Log(checkedCode.ToString());
}
```

You could also create a single string from all codes with LINQ and `String.Join`:

```
var allCodes = controleTable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>("CODE"));
Common.Log(string.Join(",", allCodes));
```

Comment: Thanks for the awnser, but i only want to loop trough CODE and not trough other rows, Can i do this the same way?

Comment: @CKY: what does that mean? How do you want o loop through a single integer?

Comment: Who said its a single interger, i have a couple of integers in the CODE

Comment: @CKY: Have a look at my edited answer. I have shown a LINQ approach that selects all codes and uses `String.Join` to concatenate them with comma.